# What data does WordPress theme update pull If there is an update?

Tags: themes

I'd like to know what WordPress pulls to notify updates from the code.

I'm currently facing an issue where my theme happens to have the same name as another theme which is already in the repository and it's notifying me that I'm currently using an older version of the theme. What's even worse, my theme gets replaced with that already existing theme when I click update.

So it'll be great if I could just change a code or two to prevent this. I've tried changing the 'Theme Name' in style.css in the root folder (do I have to wait for this to update?) but it's not working.

Note: I'm using my theme in MAMP (connected to the internet, of course).

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very typical and very annoying situation unfortunately.

WordPress doesn't "pull" update information. Instead it *submits* plugin and theme information to the API at wordpress.org, which responds with updates available. In practice matching of updates is loose and exact logic is not disclosed. Name matters a lot, folder name as well. Rest matters to some unknown degree.

The closest to solution is filtering your theme's data out of HTTP requests to the API via `http_request_args` filter. There is old post on topic [excluding your plugin or theme from update checks](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/12/14/excluding-your-plugin-or-theme-from-update-checks/), but as of recently API requests had been changed to use JSON and code no longer applies as-is.

Comment: Thanks, changing the folder name did the trick. I wouldn't want to exclude my theme from update checks cause I actually want them to update, just the right one.